# Pstore decompression failed

Tags: compression, linux-headers

I don’t understand what this error means. Can anyone help?

I’ve seen a couple of forums with the same error, but none helped me resolve it.

```
Pstore: decompression failed, ret = -22 !
Pstore: crypto_comp_decompress failed, ret = -22 !
```

Comment: There is a [workaround](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=902966;msg=10).

Answer (score 2):

Try removing pstore files with

```
sudo rm /sys/fs/pstore/dmesg-efi-*.enc.z
```

Comment: My pstore log files were called `dmesg-erst-*.enc.z`. Other than that, this solution worked for me. Thank you!